# Error on generating report

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Please help me out with this error

I have a reporting application tool which generates reports.
It doesnot generate report at all and gives this error on browser page.

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.

The status code returned from the server was: 12152
Line: 5
Char: 84171
Code: 0
URI: https://somesitexyze.com/abc/ScriptResource.axd?d=zYiIkAblLB47xmRSQ8cbVVVHq9tUpULi-QRzTKfMbkzX6vz-c4JztSX_KzKP5yxYMxFvu5Zr00Cpzq6tq1xGjO2aBVj4HyAwg6VQOg0UDXV1sj2cjRFmDMX_W7BExLYj-pExjc35B0p-6rAzMYKUwpRl_BivzxcVw1&t=ffffffff94f72c4c

I have tried to generate small data reports then its working fine but for large data its not working at all and showing the above error. Please help me out as its not getting rectified.

Comment: I checked my web config file also
maxRequestLength="200000" executionTimeout="300" requestValidationMode="2.0"

Comment: What shall i do please help as i really need to remove this error